# Transforming takes long time with st_transform

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, srid

I have two shape files contains considerably large data. I exported them to my geodatabase(using arccatolog), which takes 2 days. The problem is their srid must be changed. So i tried creating new table from the tables i exported with sde.st_transform method but the query did not end. At the end 5th day i stop the query. In previous versions of the arcgis server i use shp2sde function from linux command line and give the srid parameter directly. But in 10.2 version i could not find such a functionality. So i got only arcmap&arccatolog and SQL options. I need to set srid of this shape files before i exported them. So what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have access to Arcmap or ArcCatalog,
Use **Project** tool to simultaneously project your shape files to another coordinate system and importing them into your enterprise geodatabase!

[image: Sample project tool]

Comment: is that possible to choose output coordinate system with srid instead of name. I am asking because there are 3 coordinate system which has same in spatial references table but ony one of them has the srid i want.

Comment: To follow GIS SE rules, ask your question in another thread. Multiple questions in one question is against SE rules. Your question should be, "How to map between ArcGIS Coordinate System and EPSG SRID?"